# Calculate a tennis players chance to win a 5set match knowing he has 50% chance of winning 1SET?

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution

Is the following correct? My friend tells me i need to (add up the binomial probabilities of 2 wins in 2 sets, 2 wins in 3 sets and 2 wins in 4 sets THEN multiply the sum obtained by p)

P(3) = 5C3 x 0.5^3 x 0.5^2

Comment: Are matchups independent?

Comment: Would this be a 50% chance of *winning exactly one set,* or of *winning at least one set,* or of *winning each set*?

Answer (score 2):

The probability of winning a 5 set match is the sum of the probabilities of the events
$$\begin{align*}
 \text{win in}~ 3:&  WWW\\
\text{win in}~4:& LWWW,WLWW,WWLW\\
\text{win in}~5:& LLWWW, LWLWW,LWWLW, WLLWW, WLWLW, WWLLW
\end{align*}$$
If the probability of winning a set is $p$ and the probability of losing a set is
$q = 1-p$, the probability of winning a 5 set match works out to be
$$p^3 + 3p^3q + 6p^3q^2 = p^3(1+3q+6q^2)$$ which of course is $\frac{1}{2}$ when $p=\frac{1}{2}$ as Thierry Silbermann has already pointed out to you.  See also
an article titled "The Drunken Tennis Player" in Ian Stewart's *Game, Set and Match*.

Answer (score 2):

You and your friend are both wrong ;-)

Your binomial calculation is wrong: as the other answers show, you've calculated the chance of winning exactly 3 sets out of 5 played, which is not the same condition as winning a 5-set tennis match.

Your friend is wrong to say you "need" to use binomials at all. You could instead reason by symmetry:

Neither a set nor a match can be drawn, it must be won by one player or the other. So if one player has a $0.5$ chance of winning a set then the other has a $1 - 0.5 = 0.5$ chance of winning a set, so the same chance. Hence for both of them, the answer to this question is their chance of winning the match. Since the match must be won by exactly one of them, with equal probability, this chance must be $1 / 2 = 0.5$

Of course, doing the combinatorics puts you in a good position to answer the follow-up question, "aha, but what if the chance of winning a set is 0.55?", whereas reasoning using symmetry fails as soon as the problem is no longer symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Well to win a 5 sets match, a tennis player needs to win at least 3 sets.

During a match you can have $2^5$ possibles outcomes, and on these 32 possible outcomes, the player will win on 16 configurations (10 if he wins 3 sets, 5 if he wins 4 sets and 1 if he wins 5 sets)

Each outcome have the same probability, so the result is:

$P$(3 winning sets) + $P$(4 winning sets) + $P$(5 winning sets) $= 10/32 + 5/32 + 1/32 = 16/32$ so $1/2$ to win

You can look at this to train: http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/probability/info.htm